# Hiding post pagination behind/after the read more link

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a post entry in my blog that's split to 3 parts. In the end of the entry's first half there are 'Page 1 2 3' links displayed. On top of that, I have a 'Read More' button link after the first paragraph which (if you're on the main page, search results, archive) the user has to click first before he can see the rest of the post plus links to the 3 parts of the post.

Now my question is, how can I hide the 'Page 1 2 3' and make it show ONLY in a single post page, the page they will get to after clicking 'Read More'? I don't want the reader to see these links up front, only when he clicks the read more link button. I'd like the pagination links to be hidden in homepage, archive pages, search results.

Basically only make the post's pagination links visible in a single post (post.php is the template file probably?). How can I do that?

I thought of hiding the post pagination ('Page 1 2 3') but it doesn't seem to work. Or maybe because Genesis has no assigned class per page? Or could it be a matter of prioritization in add_filter?

I'm using WordPress and Genesis Framework. Codes I used are below:

The code that I use to make the pagination links display on the website, without it, the links become hidden:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
return $content . custom_wp_link_pages( array( 'echo' => FALSE ) );
}, -1 ); // Lower number = higher priority.
```

The code for the custom pagination links in WordPress

```
function custom_wp_link_pages( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'before' => '<p align="center" id="post-pagination">' . __( 'Pages:' ), 
        'after' => '</p>',
        'text_before' => '',
        'text_after' => '',
        'next_or_number' => 'number', 
        'nextpagelink' => __( 'Next page' ),
        'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
        'pagelink' => '%',
        'echo' => 1
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $r = apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_args', $r );
    extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

    global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more, $pagenow;

    $output = '';
    if ( $multipage ) {
        if ( 'number' == $next_or_number ) {
            $output .= $before;
            for ( $i = 1; $i < ( $numpages + 1 ); $i = $i + 1 ) {
                $j = str_replace( '%', $i, $pagelink );
                $output .= ' ';
                if ( $i != $page || ( ( ! $more ) && ( $page == 1 ) ) )
                    $output .= _wp_link_page( $i );
                else
                    $output .= '<span class="current-post-page">';

                $output .= $text_before . $j . $text_after;
                if ( $i != $page || ( ( ! $more ) && ( $page == 1 ) ) )
                    $output .= '</a>';
                else
                    $output .= '</span>';
            }
            $output .= $after;
        } else {
            if ( $more ) {
                $output .= $before;
                $i = $page - 1;
                if ( $i && $more ) {
                    $output .= _wp_link_page( $i );
                    $output .= $text_before . $previouspagelink . $text_after . '</a>';
                }
                $i = $page + 1;
                if ( $i <= $numpages && $more ) {
                    $output .= _wp_link_page( $i );
                    $output .= $text_before . $nextpagelink . $text_after . '</a>';
                }
                $output .= $after;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $echo )
        echo $output;

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Using `is_single()` inside your filter function didn't help?

Comment: I haven't thought of this solution but when I tried it.. it just hid the pagination entirely (from archive, search results, and the single page). Maybe I did it wrong. My understanding of WordPress PHP is still on newbie level, sorry.

Comment: Post the code you've tried. That way people can continue helping you.

Comment: Here `add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_wp_link_pages', -1 );
function custom_wp_link_pages( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ){
         $content = . custom_wp_link_pages( array( 'echo' => FALSE ));
      }
    return $content;
}`

Comment: It should be `$content .= custom_wp_link_pages( array( 'echo' => FALSE ));` with the `.` before the equal sign. Even so it doesn't work?

Comment: No, unfortunately it still doesn't work. :/ Thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working after forever! Total trial and error before I got it working. Here's my revised code (refer to 'code for custom pagination links' from the original question).

I put the code for custom pagination links inside `is_single`. Then the second code, the shorter one, I left it as is.

```
function custom_wp_link_pages( $args = '' ) {

if ( is_single() ) { // Start of is_single
$defaults = array(
    'before' => '<p align="center" id="post-pagination">' . __( 'Pages:' ), 
    'after' => '</p>',
    'text_before' => '',
    'text_after' => '',
    'next_or_number' => 'number', 
    'nextpagelink' => __( 'Next page' ),
    'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
    'pagelink' => '%',
    'echo' => 1
);

$r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
$r = apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_args', $r );
extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more, $pagenow;

$output = '';
if ( $multipage ) {
    if ( 'number' == $next_or_number ) {
        $output .= $before;
        for ( $i = 1; $i < ( $numpages + 1 ); $i = $i + 1 ) {
            $j = str_replace( '%', $i, $pagelink );
            $output .= ' ';
            if ( $i != $page || ( ( ! $more ) && ( $page == 1 ) ) )
                $output .= _wp_link_page( $i );
            else
                $output .= '<span class="current-post-page">';

            $output .= $text_before . $j . $text_after;
            if ( $i != $page || ( ( ! $more ) && ( $page == 1 ) ) )
                $output .= '</a>';
            else
                $output .= '</span>';
        }
        $output .= $after;
    } else {
        if ( $more ) {
            $output .= $before;
            $i = $page - 1;
            if ( $i && $more ) {
                $output .= _wp_link_page( $i );
                $output .= $text_before . $previouspagelink . $text_after . '</a>';
            }
            $i = $page + 1;
            if ( $i <= $numpages && $more ) {
                $output .= _wp_link_page( $i );
                $output .= $text_before . $nextpagelink . $text_after . '</a>';
            }
            $output .= $after;
        }
    }
}

if ( $echo )
    echo $output;

return $output;
}
} // Closing bracket of is_single
```